# Bamboo to Jenkins Migration: Can I access and compare the XML configuration files?

Tags: jenkins, bamboo

I am planning to migrate my entire project in Bamboo to Jenkins. Is there a way to export the configuration XML files of individual plans in Bamboo to create new jobs in Jenkins? I found that there are so many individual XML files present in Bamboo unlike Jenkins. Can anyone suggest the easy way to compare the XML files of both bamboo and Jenkins?

Comment: Bamboo stored data in configured database server. Might be helpful to see configured database schema for bamboo.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware Bamboo does not store its config in xml files or any other readable files but rather uses a database. This means unless you dig into the DB there is no real way to produce Jenkins config files.

For a discussion on the lack of human readable config files in Bamboo see https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-15087