# Single plan migration from Bamboo to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, bamboo

We have a plan in Bamboo which needs to be migrated to Jenkins. Could anyone please provide some advice on how to start, any tips or documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Good move.  Bamboo isn't as feature rich as Jenkins.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910932/bamboo-to-jenkins-migration) post.